# how to add static file such as css and js in html file in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new spring boot and thymeleaf.

i have try adding css file to my html file in spring boot. but nothing work

it is not working for me

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/main.css}">
```

my css file in under

```
static
---| css
     ---| main.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static directory is served from **/**.
For example, src/main/resources/static/main.css will be served from /main.css whereas src/main/resources/static/css/main.css will be served from /css/main.css.

try out this it will work for you:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css" type="text/css" th:href="@{/main.css}">
```

Please let me know if it works or not !!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your HTML file is in the templates folder if not please drag it to the templates folder then add

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
```

in your HTML file.